# How can I make an Oracle database run an external program on Windows Server?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, executable, external

I'm currently looking to make run an external program from Oracle (the goal is from a trigger, but I'm testing to simply make it work manually for now).

Maybe I'm missing something, here is what I did step by step :

- created a .bat file simply printing a line (C:\TEMP\printline.bat), that's what I want Oracle to execute (for now).

The content of the file is :

```
@echo off
echo Oracle call done !!
pause
```

- added the program in "the program list or Oracle" using this command :

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
program_name            => 'TEST_EXE',
program_type            => 'EXECUTABLE',
program_action          => 'C:\TEMP\printline.bat',
enabled                 => TRUE
);
END;
/
```

I can see it is well inserted in the table DBA_SCHEDULER_PROGRAMS.

- after many research, it looks like you don't have a command like **DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_PROGRAM**, you "MUST?" do it with jobs, so I created one, I tried these two ways :

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'TEST_EXE_JOB',
   program_name       =>  'TEST_EXE',
   enabled            =>  TRUE,
   repeat_interval    =>  'freq=yearly',
   start_date         =>  SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
   job_name           =>  'TEST_EXE_JOB',
   job_type           =>  'EXECUTABLE',
   job_action         =>  'C:\TEMP\printline.bat',
   enabled            =>  true,
   repeat_interval    =>  'freq=yearly',
   start_date         =>  SYSDATE);
end;
/
```

I set frequency yearly because I want to run the program manually anyway, and if I set it to NULL the job isn't created.

- with any of these two entries, I run the job manually with this command :

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.run_job (job_name => 'TEST_EXE_JOB');
end;
/
```

Oracle says that the PL/SQL call is well done, and I can check in the table **DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS** that there is a log line saying the call was successfully done, but nothing happened on the server, the .bat file hasn't been executed.

I also had to start the Windows service **OracleJobSchedulerORCL** to make the call successfull. If I don't start it, I get this error :

```
ORA-27370: échec du lancement d'un travail de type EXECUTABLE par le travail esclave
ORA-27300: opération dépendante du système d'exploitation : échec de accessing job scheduler service avec l'état 2
ORA-27301: message d'erreur du système d'exploitation : The system cannot find the file specified.
ORA-27302: une erreur s'est produite à : sjsec 5
ORA-27303: informations supplémentaires : The system cannot find the file specified.
ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", ligne 231
ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", ligne 568
ORA-06512: à ligne 2
27370. 00000 -  "job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE"
*Cause:    The scheduler ran into an error when the job slave tried to start
           a job of type EXECUTABLE. The rest of the error stack will provide
           more detailed information on what the exact problem was.
*Action:   Correct the problem specified in the error stack and reschedule
           the job.
```

- I also found some messages talking about the **{ORA_HOME}\rdbms\admin\externaljob.ora**, but without many explanations. It looks like to manage rights on external call, but I don't understand how it works.

So here are some questions :

- Why do I have to work with jobs and frequency ? There is no way to make manual call on a program ?
- Oracle says the job call is successfull, but nothing happens as expected. Am I missing some rights configuration or something else ?
- Is there an easier way to make Oracle run an external program ?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Remember that the bat file will run under the account that launches the OracleJobSchedulerORCL service meaning it will never appear on *your* desktop. For testing have it write to a file instead (in a location the aforementioned account has r/w access to).  You may also need the action to be cmd.exe and pass it the path to your batch file as an argument.

Comment: I checked the account used by service and found "NT SERVICE\OracleJobSchedulerORCL" account. So I changed the settings to make this account have rights to read and execute, but it changes nothing.
I replaced my .bat file with a "Hello World" console application, and a sleep of 5 seconds. Now when I run the job, I see the console executed in the Windows task manager, and a success result on Oracle side.
So I think that my issue is solved :-)
But is it the right way to use ? Manually run a scheduled job ? Is it possible to create an Oracle job not scheduled ? I found it strange...

Comment: Its the common way to do it, not sure if there are other more recent alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

A simple mechanism to run an OS command is to hook into the PREPROCESSOR option within external tables. You could so something like:

```
SQL> create table my_table (
  2   output varchar2(64)
  3  )
  4  organization external
  5  (  type oracle_loader
  6     default directory temp
  7     access parameters
  8     ( records delimited by newline
  9       preprocessor  temp:'run_os.bat'
 10     )
 11     location ( temp:'run_os.bat' )
 12  ) reject limit unlimited ;
```

and put whatever you want in "run_os.bat".

There is a full walkthrough video on my YouTube channel https://youtu.be/kMknfeGa6Ug

Comment: Thanks Connor, I'll check this for another option :-)